# I'm talking at WordPress UK Edinburgh 2012 14-15 July

Tags: discussion

Just putting out a shout out to see who from WPSE community will be attending WPUK Edinburgh 2012?

For those that are attending and didn't know, I will be doing a talk there. After doing my talk "You don't know query" at WP London, a month back, and getting good feedback I've put the same talk forward to do at WPUK Edinburgh 2012. I will be extending the talk to include more examples this time round.

So what is the aim of my talk? Well I aim to spread awareness about using query_posts() and why it's bad while showing the correct way to query posts. The talk is 80% based off Andrew Nacin's talk "You don't know query" so credits to him.

If any of you are attending then please let me know below and I'll be sure to look out for you at the event.

Comment: Did your talk get recorded?

Comment: The London talk was recorded but the audio was recorded from the camera and it didn't work too well so the recordings where scraped. The event in Edinburgh will be recorded properly I believe but just in case I will be taking my own wireless mic and recording my own audio and screen capture.

Comment: Best of luck, I'd be there if the pond between here and there weren't so big!!

Comment: At least *some* of the talks at Edinburgh will be being recorded it seems.